# Unable to set left padding for checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-checkbox

I am trying just to set the left and right space for Checkbox, to increase the tap area range.
Unfortunately, when I am trying to set the `paddingStart` in xml layout it does the wrong change and make the checkbox right padding. WTF, is there a bug in Android API or something?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cc_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</merge>
```

Preview from Android Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there a bug in Android API or something?

Not really. The reason why you saw the padding on the right even though you set it to the left is because the `paddingStart` is applied to the text the checkbox contains. Therefore, you could not see the expected padding on the left of the box.

As long as you use `android:text` (not a `TextView` aligned right next to the box), clicking on either the box or the text will activate the checkbox, meaning that it gives you what you want in terms of the click area.

However, I suppose you meant the area on the left of the box. One thing to achieve that is to create a new drawable resource file and use it in the checkbox's `android:drawableStart`.

Supposing that you named your drawable file checkbox_selector, the file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_default"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_checked"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_default"/>
</selector>
```

Then you need to remove the default box to apply the selector above as a drawable resource. For that:

```
android:button="@null"
```

Right after that, you need to call `android:drawableStart` to use the drawable you just created, and set the padding as you would like.

```
android:drawableStart="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:paddingStart="20dp"
```

The final code should look like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cc_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />
```

Comment: it seems that it is not rendering on android 6

Comment: With this solution we won't have a default checkbox animation, am I right?