# How to add padding to MaterialCheckBox?

Tags: android, material-design, android-checkbox

I'm using `<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox`

from the Material library.

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'`

I'm trying to add padding at the start of the checkbox, but using the attribute

`android:paddingStart="16dp"` does nothing.

[image]

Using the padding attribute only adds padding to the end.

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:padding="16dp"/>
```

[image]

I've tried using the two attributes

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

To remove the default padding and set it again with the padding of 16dp

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:padding="16dp"
```

This still only adds padding to the end of the checkbox.

The checkbox is in a constraintlayout and I've made sure to add constraints to the checkbox

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

But it's still not adding padding to the start of it.

Using the marginStart attribute is successfully adding a margin to the start

```
<com.google.android.material.checkbox.MaterialCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
```

[image]

How can I add padding to the checkbox?

Comment: Technically, you can't add padding there, 'cause padding on that side is the space between the drawable and the text. `CompoundButton` – which is where that drawable is handled – always aligns it right on the start side, and there is no way to adjust that; it's hard-coded. You could, however, wrap that drawable in an `InsetDrawable` that shifts it in. There are a few different ways to do that, but the options available depend on your `minSdkVersion`, and if a `MaterialCheckBox` subclass is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Unless you just want to provide your own button drawable, that is, 'cause then you can wrap it in an `<inset>` in your resources, no matter the version.

Comment: thanks, I like your inset idea better so I don't have to deal with version problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64914260/11110509 like this person who says it doesn't render on android 6. yeah, ill pass on having to deal with all that hehe

Comment: Hmm, that user's got a solid idea; I'm kinda curious what the issue is on 6. Not curious enough to investigate, though. Anyhoo, if you don't mind using a subclass, it ends up being pretty simple, and it works on all versions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-KNHuhKAv7dqr95DtrQ55mE2ixL8o0CY/view?usp=sharing. With outlines on, kinda looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDrJN.png. If you need to support RTL, it gets a little more involved, but not too much.

Comment: I've edited that example. Just a heads up. Turns out that `setButtonDrawable()` gets called multiple times during the constructors' run, and I'd not considered that.

Comment: I ended up doing it all in xml to avoid having to create an extra class for padding only. Thanks for letting me know about ```setButtonDrawable``` being called multiple times didn't know that.

Comment: Just FYI, `CompoundButton` also assumes that the button drawable is flush against the start side when it sets its background hotspot bounds, so you might end up with a ripple animation in the wrong spot. I've added a fix to the subclass example, but I'm not sure we can do the same only in XML, apart from disabling it.